# What's that series of number represent after building Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, build

when i build angular app for production, i found series of number added in reference of external files. what does this refer?

```
<script src="js/shims.js?1501242878494"></script>
<script src="js/app.js?1501242878496"></script>
```

Comment: That is the unique hash assigned by ng cli while giving production build. So that it will be easily identified and differentiated in production environment at later stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series of number is nothing but hash that is generated by Angular while building the application.

If you donot want these hash then use this command in cli

```
ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing none
```